# Fix Firebase Error due to multiple firebase initialization

Tags: node.js, firebase

I'm working on an app that uses **firebase** as the database. We use firebase-admin on the backend (A REST API built on Node Express) only for operations that require admin permissions such as User Authentication, User Account Deletion or the likes. Let's say we have an endpoint like:

```
app.post('/auth/user/signin', function(req, res){
    const ev = req.body;
    const email = ev.email;
    const password = ev.password;

    firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
      credential: {some admin creds}),
      databaseURL: {some database URL}
    });

    return someFirebaseAuthQuery()
     .then(() => {

        // Some auth related code
        ...
        ...
        ...

        firebaseAdmin.auth().app.delete();
        return res.
           status(some status).
           json(some data);
     })
});
```

The problem we face is that when two users make a sign in request simultaneously, the firebaseAdmin.initializeApp() is called twice (once per user) which throws an error that says something like *Firebase App already exists*. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not create an instance every time you get a request. This is not the right way to do it if you are running an express app. Though if you are hosting your app on cloud function then it will run fine.

The error here is you are trying to initialize firebaze admin app two times with the same name and that is "default"

If you can see the defination of the initializeApp that take two argument and as you are giving only one argument so it will take "default" as a name by default.

```
initializeApp(options, name) returns admin.app.App
```

So best way to achieve this is make one file to initialize admin app when express app starts and export that instance and use that in your app whever you need that

**firebaseConfig.js**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
});

module.exports.admin = admin
```

and in your route handling file

**example.js**

```
const { admin } = require('./firebaseConfig.js');

app.post('/auth/user/signin', function(req, res){
    const ev = req.body;
    const email = ev.email;
    const password = ev.password;

    return someFirebaseAuthQuery()
    .then(() => {

        // Some auth related code
        ...
        ...
        ...
        // do not need to delete app
        return res.
        status(some status).
        json(some data);
    })
});
```

or if you want to continue with your flow then give some unique identifier to initialize app like following.

```
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: {some admin creds}),
  databaseURL: {some database URL}
}, "UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER");
```

**But later is not encouraged for the very obvious reasons**

I hope this will solve your concerns

Comment: Hi, Ridham! Thank You for your kind reply. :) I have a doubt though. Where would I put the code "firebaseAdmin.auth().app.delete();" if I initialize firebase in some firebaseConfig.js file as suggested by you. We must delete the app somewhere in the code to make the changes persistent to the firebase database, right?

Comment: you dont need to delete the app to persist the changes in RTDB, You can configure you app to be deleted at the time your express app stops, but that to eventually not needed as firebase sdk ref will be removed by js when your app is stopped

Comment: this solution seems to go against the serverless approach where we want to not have a custom server file. What would be a good solution to that problem?

Answer (score 2):

firebase need to be initialised only once. So `firebaseAdmin.initializeApp` should be called once when the app is initialised. It should be outside `app.post`

Comment: Where to put "firebaseAdmin.auth().app.delete();" then? Or, it's not necessary to delete the app after initialisation.

Comment: you can delete when the express app is stoped, you can push all the firebase request into a promise array, and use `Promise.all` to make sure that all the requests has been completed before you call `firebaseAdmin.auth().app.delete()`.

Comment: this solution seems to go against the serverless approach where we want to not have a custom server file. What would be a good solution to that problem?

Comment: @ZenVentzi We are in the same position. We are creating and deleting the app everytime we interact with firebase (sometimes it could be a single message). We found that lambda's do not finish (i.e., nodejs process still running) without running app.delete()!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can manage multiple apps with firebase-admin on nodejs

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const service1 = require('./app1-service.json');
const service2 = require('./app2-service.json');

const apps = {
  app1: null,
  app2: null,
};

void init() {
  // check and init app1
  const initialisedApps = admin.apps.map((item) => item.name);
  if (!initialisedApps.includes('app1')) {
    apps.app1 = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(service1),
    }, 'app1');
  } else apps.app1 = admin.app('app1');
  
  // check and init app2
  if (!initialisedApps.includes('app2')) {
    apps.app2 = admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(service2),
    }, 'app2');
  } else apps.app2 = admin.app('app2');
}
```